# javascript make bucket of google cloud storage public to a specific URL or website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, iframe, google-cloud-storage

Firebase hosting my website. Website has a `<iframe>` element, it will load `aaa.html` from bucket in google cloud storage.

> `<iframe src="https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/aaa.html" />`

And `aaa.html` will also load other files (`js` files or `img` files) stored in the same bucket.

When I use `gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://bucket` to set bucket public and all files public, website works perfectly. But I do not want that users could link `aaa.html` without my website. Set bucket public is seems to be incorrect.

So, is there a way to make bucket public to a specific website?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. You mentioned you don't want to make your bucket public. Singed URLs are not for you.

I think you can achieve your goal by doing the following:

1. Define a service account with the roles and permissions you need to get the stored objects in your bucket. This service account will be used by your application.
2. Use the [GCS API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) to get into the stored files in your bucket. Here is how to [Use a service account to call an API in your code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually)

Hope this is helpful :D

Comment: Thank you for reply. I set `serviceAccount.json` with `firebase-admin `and `@google-cloud/storage` in cloud functions. When I use same way to load `aaa.html` in front by `<iframe>`, I got access denied with anonymous caller. What should I do to load `aaa.html` in website?

Comment: In cloud functions, I can return url of `aaa.html` by `.getSignedUrl`. Then `<iframe>` load url. But I only got `aaa.html`, `aaa.html` did not load other files (js files and image files), and like you said signed url is not for me. I really don't know how to load `aaa.html` in right way.

Comment: The links I shared with you are for calling the API from the back-end. And you're trying to call it from the front-end. Hmm, how about this? Call the API from your back how the docs say and add the results with jQuery in your page. This is how you add elements to your html file dynamically with jQuery:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp 

Tell me how it goes :D

Comment: Let me apologize, I am too anxious to describe my problem clearly. I was want to know is there had a way that only use front-end to load successfully. In cloud functions, should I "get" `aaa.html` url? or "download" `aaa.html`?

Comment: Don't worry. I like to help. I think that you should use the signed URL in that case. I couldn't find a way to pass the credentials from the front. But doing this, will make your object public to anyone who has that URL.

Comment: In order to avoid using signed urls, I highly recommend you to call the API at least from your JavaScript files with Ajax or like the docs I shared with you say. Apart from that, I think there's no way to achieve your goal. Good luck! :)